# Folder organization for ASP.NET access performance

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an sql table of orders, each order has an order_id primary key.
each order is linked to a 3 images, name of image is order_id+1/2/3.png
When user will load the order on ASPX page i need to load the all 3 images.

Will it be best to save all images in same folder ORDERS/IMAGES/order_id+1/2/3.png, if so, it will be a folder with huge number of images that will grow all the time, but the call from site will be always to specific file name.

Or, To open inner folder for each order ORDERS/IMAGES/order_id/
and inside this folder to just save the files and to call them later.
In that way i will have to create inner folder each time the images are uploaded and also this way i will have a huge number of folders(per order) inside the main orders folder.

My biggest concern is for loading speed and server resources(cpu,ram) while calling images to the ASPX page and while uploading the images to server.

Comment: Generally, web server’s file system is not an ideal place to store dynamic amount of images. There are superior cloud based alternatives. This question will be extremely opinion based and to be honest, looks like an XY problem to me.

Comment: What you mean by superior cloud based alternatives?

Comment: Like azure blob storage, that kind of thing